How to replace excel cell value using VBA code?
I'm pretty new to using VBA codes and struggling with the following.
Simplified example (which also doesn't work): cell B1=5, through usage of VBA code I want to change this value to 10.
If in my line of code I write ws.range("B1").value = 10, nothing happens when I run the function. If I, however, write ws.range("B1").clearcontents it does clear out cell B1.
I originally tried this on my work laptop, but also in new excel (xlsm) files and on my private laptop (enabling all VBA macros).
Any idea how I can fix this?
Thanks!

we need to see the rest of your code

If you want to call this as a custom function in a worksheet (UDF), then such functions generally shouldn't change cell values. You can do this with a Sub macro that you can launch with a button, or with a keyboard shortcut. Such a macro is performed once.
The function, on the other hand, recalculates after each change in the worksheet. So if you had a function in a worksheet that would insert 10 into a cell, you wouldn't be able to insert any other value, because the function would constantly change it. Exceptionally, the Range.ClearContents operation can be performed with the UDF function, but this is probably some kind of oversight of the manufacturer.
